# DialogFragment. Listener. Orientation changed. Activity is null

Tags: android

Here is the code:

```
class AddVideoDialog : DialogFragment(), EnterPasswordDialog.OKDialogListener
{
    @SuppressLint("InflateParams")
    override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog
    {
        .
        .
        .
        enterPasswordDialog.show(fragmentManager, "enterPassword")
        enterPasswordDialog.mListener = this
        .
        .
        .
        return builder.create()
    }

    override fun onDialogOK()
    {
        .
        .
        .
        //The problem is here! activity is null after orientation change.
        val mainFragment = activity.fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(Brain.MAIN_FRAGMENT_TAG) as MainFragment
        .
        .
        .
    }
}
```

When the above DialogFragment is shown, if the user performs an orientation change, the activity is null in the `OKDialogListener` callback. Can somebody please explain to Me why it is so? Thanks.

Comment: Where does `activity`get its value in the first place? Did you set it somewhere in AddVideoDialog?

Comment: No, I did not set it in AddVideoDialog. Its the usual property of every Fragment (or DialogFragment because it inherits from Fragment), in Java it would be getActivity().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for translating ;) Kotlin is interesting but I'm very much a beginner there.

What I can see though is that in `onCreateDialog()` you set the listener to be the current `DialogFragment`. I suspect that the `Dialog` which is shown after the orientation change still holds on to that listener. Because this listener (= the original `DialogFragment`) is not attached to an `Activity` any more, `getActivity()` respectively `activity` is `null`. So you have to set the listener at a point where you can be sure that the `DialogFragment` is  attached to the current `Activity`.

Comment: Thank You very much for Your answer. I had a feeling it was something like that but I could quite put in words like You :-) Eventually, I found the exact thing that was happening. When EnterPasswordDialog was appearing, the AddVideoDialog was going thru `onPause` and the call to `activity` was null inside `onDialogOK` because the dialog already went thru `onPause`.